# Adding the same component in a table?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, vaadin

So I already accomplished inserting a component in a table using a button event. The next thing I'm trying to do is add the same component in the table for example a Select Component that has the items A and B. Everytime I clicked the button a the Select Component appears then I clicked the button again to create another row of components but the Select Component transfers to the second row rather than adding a new one. So how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Every `Component` (e.g. `Button` or `Select`) you see has its own representation on the server. You can't show the same `Component` more than once. Generate a new `Select` component for every row you add to the table. You might want to read the part about `FieldFactory`s (5.16.3) in the [vaadin book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.table.html).

Comment: What i'm trying to do is when I click the button a new Select Component with the same items on it as the first Select will appear on the next row.

Comment: Just create a new Select and add the same items to the new Select. Add this new Select to the table.